# cannot print the result of a getDay() method

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javascript so I was trying to apply the first things I learned to exercise a bit. At first I tried to create a .html file, then link it to an external .js file and write some lines.

More specifically I tried to print on my page the result of applying the getDay() method to the date of today. Here's how I wrote it :

```js
const now = Date();

const today = now.getDay();

document.write(today);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js" type=text/javascript></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me why my getDay() method won't work? It's not a problem of linking because writing other stuff works.

I'm not looking for a workaround but just an explanation to understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: You're missing `new` in front of `Date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the  [`new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) to create an instance of *Date* object:

> The [`new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

```js
const now = new Date();

const today = now.getDay();

document.write(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Date()` does not create a date object, you have to use `new` before it to instanciate a date object.

```html
const now = new Date();

const today = now.getDay();

document.write(today);
```